# iOS11 programmatically turn off `safeAreaInsets`

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I'd like my `collectionView` to bleed behind the status bar in iOS 11... however the content of my `collectionView` is always offset `20.0` apparently due to `safeAreaInsets`

Is there a way to turn this off in code and handle manually? I can't seem to find it...

thanks in advance

Comment: `insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea = false` maybe.. or possibly: `additionalSafeAreaInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero` or `contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never`.. Didn't test either.

Comment: `insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea` sounds right, but it didn't change anything when I set it to false

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found it, you need to set `contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior` to `.never`

Comment: You saved my day! Hours of googling didn't help until your answer! Btw, it affects any UIScrollView, not only CollectionView, that's why it's a miracle I've found your answer! Thank you a million my friend!

Comment: Cool, let me add some more tags then